# How can Android Live Data that is derived from a switchMap be tested with junit and mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, android-livedata

I am writing a unit test to assert `LiveData` observers are being called with expected arguments. I have had success testing `LiveData` by using the `InstantTaskExecutorRule`, mocking an observer, and observing the data via the `observeForever` method.

When using the same approach with `LiveData` that is derived from a `Transformations.switchMap` assertions are failing.

For Example:

```
class LoginViewModel {
    @Inject lateinit var service: LoginService

    val passwordField = ObservableField<String>()

    private val loginInput = SingleLiveEvent<String>()
    val loginEvent: LiveData<UserNotification> = 
    Transformations.switchMap(loginInput, { password ->
        service.login(password)
    })

    fun login() {
       loginInput.value = passwordField.get()
    }
}
```

*SingleLiveEvent taken from the [Google Samples Repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)

And then the corresponding test (using mockito_kotlin):

```
class LoginViewModelTest {

@Rule
@JvmField
val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

//...Setup mock login service, assign it to the view model to be tested, etc

@Test
fun login() {
    val observer = mock<Observer<UserNotification>>()
    loginViewModel.loginEvent.observeForever(observer)
    loginViewModel.passwordField.set(testPassword)
    loginViewModel.login()

    //Theese verify checks report zero interactions
    verify(loginService, atLeastOnce()).login(testPassword)
    verify(observer).onChanged(expectedNotification)
}
```

Mockito reports that both of the mocks (the login service, and the observer) had zero interactions and the tests fails.

Any thoughts on how to implement this test so that the mocked classes are properly called?

Thanks in advance!

*Additional Notes:*

1. I tried using the `CountingTaskExecutorRule` in combination with `Awaitility` to wait to execute the calls to `verify` when `CountingTaskExecutorRule` reported idle, but with no luck.
2. The `login` method on the service returns `LiveData`

Comment: `SingleLiveEvent` supports only one observer. You have two: the observe call and `Transformations.switchMap()` also creates one internally.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK - thanks for the suggestion - I ended fixing the test by ```spy```ing on a concrete implementation of the ```LoginService``` interface in stead of a mock. For a reason I cannot yet fully explain, this works.